# gpart finds partitions but puts zeroes on all their specs

Tags: hard-disk, data-recovery, ntfs, mbr

So this isn't my hard drive I'm working on so I'm not too sure how it got into this state. My friend had Windows XP on it and wasn't using it much then suddenly it wouldn't boot anymore. He just wants some files back, doesn't necessarily want it fixed.

I booted up an ubuntu LiveUSB but it wouldn't mount the partitions. I tried the testdisk utility that found the partitions but wasn't able to write the table to the MBR.

Then I tried finding the partitions with gpart but it gives me this output:

```
Guessed primary partition table:
Primary partition(1)
   type: 000(0x00)(unused)
   size: 0mb #s(0) s(0-0)
   chs:  (0/0/0)-(0/0/0)d (0/0/0)-(0/0/0)r

Primary partition(2)
   type: 000(0x00)(unused)
   size: 0mb #s(0) s(0-0)
   chs:  (0/0/0)-(0/0/0)d (0/0/0)-(0/0/0)r

Primary partition(3)
   type: 000(0x00)(unused)
   size: 0mb #s(0) s(0-0)
   chs:  (0/0/0)-(0/0/0)d (0/0/0)-(0/0/0)r

Primary partition(4)
   type: 000(0x00)(unused)
   size: 0mb #s(0) s(0-0)
   chs:  (0/0/0)-(0/0/0)d (0/0/0)-(0/0/0)r
```

Does anyone know what this means?

Comment: Try the `testdisk` utility from your package manager.

Comment: I have tried testdisk, it found the partitions but but gave a Write Error when trying to rewrite the partition table. That's when I tried gpart and got the above output. I am now trying PhotoRec but all the files it recovers seem to be gibberish. I'll wait until it finishes and see maybe the ones I need would be ok

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that `gpart` is failing to read the disk but failing to handle the error properly and reporting all-zeros data instead of displaying an error message. That's consistent with the other things you tried: the live Ubuntu couldn't read the partition table either; testdisk found the partitions by searching for content that looked like the start of a filesystem, but was unable to write a partition table because the part of the disk that contains the partition table is not working.

If you want to recover some data, the first thing to do is **don't try to write to the disk**. Writing to the disk may damage it further and may overwrite some good data if you make the slightest mistake. The first thing to do is to copy the whole disk to another.

[ddrescue](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/) is a great tool for that. It copies the input file to the output file, with some added features: it keeps a log of what it's done, so it can resume after some failures; it skips over unreadable parts, but can try to fill them again later; it tries large reads, and if they fail it tries to read smaller portions that may be recoverable. So use `ddrescue` to make a disk image as a file somewhere, with a command like

```
ddrescue /dev/sdb /large-disk/failing-disk.img /large-disk/failing-disk.ddrescue.log
```

Often, when disks are failing, they work better when they're cold. Put the disk in a USB enclosure and run a first pass with `ddrescue`. If the disk runs out of steam in the middle, power it down, wait a few minutes, and try again. If the disk just won't start, putting it in the freezer for a while sometimes helps.

Once you have a disk image as a file, with everything you could read, you can start using forensic tools such as testdisk. If you make any modification to the image, be sure to take a backup in case you make a mistake.

Comment: thanks a lot, but at the moment I don't have a disk big enough to copy the whole disk. I'll give it a try when I get one